# creating multiple columns in a for loop python

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I'm new to Python.
I'm trying to create multiple columns in a for loop but I'm having trouble with it.
I have several columns and I'm trying to create a new column that shows whether or not the elements in ohlcs is greater than elements in metrics. I can do it to create one column but I want to save time since I plan on doing the same function but for different variables.

```
ohlcs = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']
metrics = ['vwap', '9EMA', '20EMA']
wip = []
for idx, row in master_df.iterrows():
    for ohlc in ohlcs:
        for metric in metrics:
            row[f'{ohlc} above {metric}'] = np.where(row[ohlc] >= row[metric], 1, 0)
```

This didn't do anything.
I've also done this:

```
ohlcs = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']
metrics = ['vwap', '9EMA', '20EMA']
wip = []
for idx, row in master_df.iterrows():
    for ohlc in ohlcs:
        for metric in metrics:
           if master_df[ohlc] >= master_df[metric]: 
               master_df[f'{ohlc} above {metric}'] = 1
           else:
               master_df[f'{ohlc} above {metric}'] = 0
```

That gave me an error.

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I did other things but I erased those as I worked on it. At this point I'm out of ideas. Please help!

I got it now but I checked manually to see if the values lined up and it wasn't.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUYr1.png)

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to iterate over the rows of the dataframe. This will give you the required result:

```py
for ohlc in ohlcs:
    for metric in metrics:
        master_df[f'{ohlc} over {metric}'] = (master_df[ohlc] >= master_df[metric]).astype(int)
```

The part `astype(int)` is just to convert `True` and `False` into `1` and `0`, if you are okay with `True` and `False` representation, you can use just `master_df[f'{ohlc} over {metric}'] = master_df[ohlc] >= master_df[metric]`.

EDIT: Of course, `(master_df[ohlc] >= master_df[metric]).astype(int)` is equivalent to `np.where(master_df[ohlc] >= master_df[metric], 1, 0)`, you can use either.

Comment: Thank you so much. I worked on this for hours and I always seem to get close. I just overcomplicate it haha.

Comment: I looked into the columns manually to see if it was right. It wasn't exactly. How do I fix that? I edited the post and attached a picture above. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, that's a strange behavior indeed. There may be a problem with types of your columns. Try using `master_df.info()` to see datatypes of your columns, possibly some are understood as strings? If datatypes are mismatched, you can try `np.where(master_df[ohlc].astype(float) >= master_df[metric].astype(float), 1, 0)`.

Comment: It shows them both as float64. The results I got are integers but the columns used to get that were all float64. Is that weird?

Comment: That's not weird, result of the comparision is `0` or `1`, so we would expect integer type. As for the wrong result of the comparision, I can't tell what the problem could be. Are you sure you're not setting up values of `open above vwap` somewhere else in the code? And are other `above` columns correct? Perhaps you can provide some sample data.

Comment: Actually what you did was perfect. I'm so sorry. I created a new line and put your correction in and named it 'open over vwap' not 'open above vwap' which is what existed before. 

Thank you again sir!

Comment: Hah, sorry, I didn't realise I replaced `above` with `over`. Also, if the answer helped you, you can accept it (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ). Good luck with your coding.

Comment: Oh ok cool! I was looking for a similar function to the reddit excel forum. Like Solution Verified. I'll do that then. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Consider `itertools.product` and the functional form [**`DataFrame.ge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) for all pairwise possibilities fir a flatter looping:

```py
from itertools import product
...

ohlcs = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']
metrics = ['vwap', '9EMA', '20EMA']

pairs = product(ohlcs, metrics)

for ohlc, metric in pairs:
    master_df[f"{ohlc} over {metric}"] = master_df[ohlc].ge(master_df[metric])
```